# Disable network on a Windows Xp PC

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking

I need to test how an application that uses an Internet connection to work behaves when there is no Internet. I disable/enable my network connection each time to test. Is there a way to do this in a single click using software?

Comment: ... What's wrong with pulling the plug?

Comment: I am looking for something easier. The plug is behind the desk and is hard to reach.

Comment: So then get a coupler, or a switch you can put on the desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a batch file with the code

```
ipconfig /release
pause > nul
ipconfig /renew
```

just run the batch file to disconnect then press any key to restore network connectivity.

Comment: Exactly what I need!

Comment: I would put an "echo Press any key to enable network..." before the pause, just in case you forget what the window is for (maybe you take a break or something)...

Comment: I created two batch files NetOff.bat and NetOn.bat

Comment: If they're short @Gerhard: paste them in your answer and I will add them to @john's answer. Great to hear his solution worked!

Comment: netoff.bat contains `ipconfig /release` and neton.bat contains `ipconfig /renew`
 These commands can also be used with AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 0):

You could download some macro recorder, and record a macro for both enabling and disabling the network adapter(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Net Profiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/) to disable/enable your internet connection. Create a profile for your current settings by which internet is enabled. Create another profile with a false proxy server by which internet is disabled. Then you can switch between these profiles to enable/disable the internet connection.